# How to attach file in email using woo commerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, email-attachments

I am using the woo commerce plugin for payment gateway .In the function.php ,I have written this code for attaching  a one image in email.but I am not able to achieve this anybody having any idea how to achieve this.

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-emails.php');

    function send_invoice () 
    {
        $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/includes/Desert.jpg' );
        wp_mail( 'sanjaynakate@gmail.com', 'Attachment test', 'The message', 'header', $attachments);
    }
       add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'send_invoice' );
```

Comment: var_dump( $attachments); you arent getting correct file path i guess

Comment: Can you explain please @pr1nc3